# simple_html_dom: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in

Tags: simple-html-dom

This code has been working good for months. The output consisted of a few lines containing statistics for a given username. The website from which the html page is taken is not down, and the content of the page in `file_get_html` hasn't changed.
All of a sudden (I checked and nobody modified it) it stopped working. Here's the relevant part:

```
[...]if ($FileAge > ($expiretime * 60) || 0 == filesize($cachename))
{
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.foo.com/search?what=user%3A'.YOUR_USER.'&search=Search');
    var_dump($html); //TEST
    $link = $html->find('.likeh4 lightGrey.', 0)->find('a', 0)->href;   // Get the last activity link
[...]
```

The error log says:

```
[02-Feb-2013 17:02:19 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /foo.php on line 22 (the line with $link).
```

`var_dump($html)` gives `bool(false)`

I have a similar script which parses an html page from another website. It stopped working as well.

```
[...]include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://my.flightmemory.com/'.FLIGHTMEMORY_USER);
$chilometri_table = $html->find('table', 2);    [...]
```

I tried to save on my webserver one of those html pages and I don't get such error.
Did my host disable some php function for security reasons? (actually, file_get_html comes from simple_html_dom and not from php native functions)

Any hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is probably way too late but:
Simple_html_dom has a constant to check given html size - `MAX_FILE_SIZE`. by default it's 600KB. It's enough for most cases, but if your given html is bigger than that, it will fail and returns `false` and causes that fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get [href]
I had same problem and fixed it.
need valid it's a simple_html_dom_node

```
if(is_a($html->find('.likeh4 lightGrey. a', 0),'simple_html_dom_node' )
  $link = $html->find('.likeh4 lightGrey. a', 0)->href;
```

OR

```
foreach ( $$html->find('.likeh4 lightGrey. a') as $links ) {
 $link =$links->href;
}
```